# How to find what arguments are passed to a Scala main class from oozie spark action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, oozie

I'm trying to figure out if I can access the name parameter from `<name>[SPARK JOB NAME]</name>` inside the Scala class, when running a spark application.

Spark Action: https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_SparkActionExtension.html

Syntax:

```
<workflow-app name="[WF-DEF-NAME]" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.3">
    ...
    <action name="[NODE-NAME]">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>[JOB-TRACKER]</job-tracker>
            <name-node>[NAME-NODE]</name-node>
            <prepare>
               <delete path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
               <mkdir path="[PATH]"/>
               ...
            </prepare>
            <job-xml>[SPARK SETTINGS FILE]</job-xml>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>[PROPERTY-NAME]</name>
                    <value>[PROPERTY-VALUE]</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
            <master>[SPARK MASTER URL]</master>
            <mode>[SPARK MODE]</mode>
            <name>[SPARK JOB NAME]</name>
            <class>[SPARK MAIN CLASS]</class>
            <jar>[SPARK DEPENDENCIES JAR / PYTHON FILE]</jar>
            <spark-opts>[SPARK-OPTIONS]</spark-opts>
            <arg>[ARG-VALUE]</arg>
                ...
            <arg>[ARG-VALUE]</arg>
            ...
        </spark>
        <ok to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
        <error to="[NODE-NAME]"/>
    </action>
    ...
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few test scripts, and I could access only the arguments enclosed in the `<arg><arg/>` tags.

Thank you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).